# regex expression for string.split() that splits a string on urls

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a regex expression for finding url's in a string, but when I use it with String.prototype.split() it returns undefined's.

```js
const regex = /(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g;
const str = "yay http://www.google.com woo www.google.com haha google.com";

console.log(str.match(regex));
// [ 'http://www.google.com', 'www.google.com', 'google.com' ]

console.log(str.split(regex));
// [ 'yay ','http://w',undefined,undefined,'',' woo ',undefined,undefined,'www.','',' haha ',undefined,undefined,undefined,'','' ]
```

After some research it appears that this has to do with capturing groups. I attempted adding `:?` to all the capturing groups (parts wrapped in parenthesis) and it removed the undefined's.

```js
const reg2 = /(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/.)?(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g

const str = "yay http://www.google.com woo www.google.com haha google.com";

console.log(str.split(reg2));
// [ 'yay ', ' woo ', ' haha ', '' ]
```

But it is omitting the urls. I am looking to return:

```
[ 'yay ', 'http://www.google.com', ' woo ', 'www.google.com', ' haha ', 'google.com' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to just split on whitespace here:

```js
var str = "yay http://www.google.com woo www.google.com haha google.com";
var parts = str.split(/\s+/);
console.log(parts);
```

If the leading/trailing whitespace are really required here, then try matching on the pattern:

```
<URL>|\s*\S+\s*
```

This would match either a URL, or a series of non word characters, with surrounding whitespace.  Consider:

```js
var str = "yay http://www.google.com woo www.google.com haha google.com";
console.log(str.match(/(?:http(s)?:\/\/.)?(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)|\s*\S+\s*/g));
```

This uses an alternation trick to first try to selectively consume a URL, with no surrounding whitespace.  That failing, the fallback pattern is `\s*\S\s*`, i.e. any other word with the leading/trailing whitespace.